# Thymol Blue - molar absorptivity

Tags: spectrophotometry, optical-properties

I did a lab about spectrophotometry and right now I need the molar absorptivity(ε) of thymol blue in acidic solution and also in basic solution. I have tried looking online but I haven't found the data I need.

What is the molar absorptivity of thymol blue in acidic solution and in basic solution?
 **information**
The specific wavelength is 540.27 nm for the acid and 601.88 nm  for the base.

Comment: Are you certain that the purpose of the lab was not to find the molar absorptivity by plotting absorbance as a function of concentration of thymol blue in both acid and base? The slope of that line will be the molar absorptivity times the path length: $$\begin{align} Abs&=\epsilon \ell c\\ y&=mx+b \\ m&=\epsilon \ell\end{align}$$

Comment: that is exactly what I did and I have my own results but now  I need to calculate the percent error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, molar absorptivity is dependent on wavelength, so you either need to specify a wavelength or you need the entire spectrum.

When searching for absorptivity, it's often effective to search for the older name 'extinction coefficient'. Using that search term in Google, I found an absorption spectrum for thymol blue [here](http://www.phywe-es.com/index.php/fuseaction/download/lrn_file/versuchsanleitungen/P3031101/e/LEC03_11_LV.pdf) (pdf).

Comment: The wavelength of choice has a maximum absorbance. The molar absorptivity is not usually calculated for other wavelengths.

Comment: It's often calculated at the isobestic wavelength.

Comment: If you use the isbestic wavelength, you only find out how much thymol blue is in the solution; you don't find out the pH of the solution, which is the purpose of using the pH indicator.

Comment: I added the wavelengths in which the experiments have been done. And also,I was not able to find the information I need in that pdf document.

Comment: Just read them off the graph at Fig. 2. For the acid at 540 nm (are you sure that's the right wavelength? It's a weird wavelength to measure the acid form at) it looks like it's about 0.05 L.(mol.cm)^-1, and for the base at 600 nm it looks like it's about 0.85 L(mol.cm)^-1. You may want to measure that graph more precisely than my eyeball did.